# is it possible to execute OpenCL code on ARM CPU (Cortex-a7) using the Mali OpenCL SDK?

Tags: arm, opencl, cortex-a8, mali

Mali OpenCL SDK allows executing opencl code on the Mali GPU.
Is it possible to execute OpenCL code on ARM CPU (Cortex-a7) using the Mali OpenCL SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at present - ARM have only publicly released drivers that support OpenCL on Mali GPUs. However, a couple of months ago they passed conformance for OpenCL running on an ARM CPU, so one might expect that this will be possible in the future:

(from the [Khronos conformant products page](http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opencl))

```
ARM Limited   2014-06-13   OpenCL_1_1
Linux 3.9.0 with ARM drivers on v7 CPU   Compute Device Type: CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
                                         Compute Device Name: ARM Cortex-A15 NEON
                                         Compute Device Version: OpenCL 1.1
                                         Compute Device Driver Version: 1.1
```

Another option for running OpenCL on ARM CPUs is to use [pocl](https://github.com/pocl/pocl), an open-source project.