# Opencl on mali SDK

Tags: arm, opencl, mali

I have a Juno ARM versatile board,which has ARM CPUs and Mali GPU. We think to use OpenCL which will be useful in such a heterogeneous platform.I think i should have a OpenCL SDK for ARM, enabling me to write programs for host ARM CPU, which will actually trigger kernels to be run on GPU. Is this understanding of mine right?
 I was searching for OpenCL SDK for ARM(to write programs for the host ARM) and found none.Instead, I found OpenCL SDK for Mali GPU on ARM's website(http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/sdks/mali-opencl-sdk/).
    Will i be able to use Mali GPU's OpenCL SDK for ARM as well ? Can someone please throw some light on this ?

Comment: OpenCL is a means to allow general-purpose computation on GPUs. You don't need such a thing for CPUs, because general-purpose computation is _what they already do_.

Comment: @Notlikethat: I am afraid if i am missing something.But I think,if I want to run specific applications on specific Processing units (like a GPU,DSP etc), then i should use OpenCL right? In that case i would require OpenCL SDK for ARM right ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263497/is-it-possible-to-execute-opencl-code-on-arm-cpu-cortex-a7-using-the-mali-open)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should be able to run OpenCL kernels on GPU of your Juno board if you have Mali driver & OpenCL SDK.