# OpenCL with ARM NEON (without Mali GPU) available?

Tags: opencl, neon

I working on customized SoC with ARM Cortex-A9.

It supports NEON, but do not has Mali GPU.

**With system, can I use OpenCL with NEON?**

I found OpenCL SDK for Mali at ARM website.

(http://malideveloper.arm.com/resources/sdks/mali-opencl-sdk/)

but there isn't any words support NEON.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263497/is-it-possible-to-execute-opencl-code-on-arm-cpu-cortex-a7-using-the-mali-open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARM have [previously announced OpenCL for NEON](https://www.arm.com/about/newsroom/media-alert-arm-extends-opencl-to-the-arm-cortex-a-processor-family.php), but these were not directly available to the public, and the 'opencl-for-neon' link on that page now just redirects to the Mali developer page.

You could instead use [pocl](https://github.com/pocl/pocl), an open source implementation of OpenCL that runs on many different platforms, include ARM CPUs with NEON.

Comment: Thank you for your answer jprice.  I will try pocl. :)

Answer (score 0):

There exist some third party research work on this topic

they created a framework for OpenCL to make use of NEON instructions

check here:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261176555_OpenCL_framework_for_ARM_processors_with_NEON_support

Comment: The implementation they have used for their paper appears to remain private.